# htaccess and ending slash

Tags: apache-2.2, .htaccess, redirect, seo

Trying to add ending slash to all urls. Here is the code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.xml$
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/])$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```

It works BUT. When visiting http://www.example.com// you get a clone of index page. This is not good for seo. However http://www.example.com/articles// redirects fine to http://www.example.com/articles/
How to deal with double slash in index? Need help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```

You can add your exceptions where I wrote `...` and it will redirect only if there is not already a trailing slash.

**EDIT:**

found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846225/remove-multiple-trailing-slashes-mod-rewrite) and verified that it works:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=""
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s//+(.*)\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\s(.*/)/+\sHTTP/[0-9.]+$
RewriteRule .* http://%{HTTP_HOST}/%1 [R=301,L]
```

This should do what you are trying...

Comment: don't work... Same thing.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks, Seybsen! Your second paste works. However I fixed it with this:
`RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.com$ [NC]`

`RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.example.com$1 [R=301,L]`
But your code is more flexible.